# Google Maps Drawer

Tags: android, slider, maps, drawer

I'm making an android app that has a map, and then when you click on a button, a drawer appears from the bottom and displays information. I actually want to do it pretty much exactly the way the Google Maps app works. When you search for directions, then pick your route, you see the polyline on the map, and a drawer appears on the bottom. How do they do this? I've tried using https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel to add a drawer, but I can't make it so that it's visibility is "gone" and then set it to visible later in. It never appears.

I've also tried using a Navigation Drawer, but this doesn't seem like the right effect. I don't want people to be able to just slide it open whenever.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to hide the view and set its height to zero. That's what I did on my code.

Comment: Try Android Navigation View with a `layout_gravity="bottom"` attribute.